# Phonegap Background Task Scheduler (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, background, task, scheduler

I want to do the following:

Create a Phonegap service that runs in the background even if the android app is not open.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

To prevent the app from being paused while in background, the backroundMode.enable interface has to be calle, like this:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

So, the backgroundMode.isActive interface can be used to get the information if the background mode is active:

Then, the backgroundMode.onactivate interface can be used to get notified when the background mode has been activated.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled();

cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {};
```

See the link to more detailed information, I have helped.